# using browsersync with rails - watching the compiled css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, watch

I'm trying to use [browser sync](https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync) with rails, using the asset pipeline.

I'm trying to use [browsersync](https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync) in my rails app. It has many wonderful features, watching css files for changes and injecting those changes to the page is one of those features.

By default, rails compiles sass to css when they are requested. So, afaik,it's not possible to give browsersync the path to the app.css.

In my browser sync config file -

```
files: ["rails/doesnt/have/the/css/yet/application/so/i/dont/know.what/to/do.css", ]
```

If I point the config towards the sass files, the page reloads(full refresh) rather than injecting the changes. This is bad. I want the css changes injected to the page.

```
files: ["assets/application.scss", ] //this causes full page refresh, which is bad.
```

Anyone know how I can point browsersync to the compiled css?

Comment: I'm also following this question

Answer (score -1):

If this is in development, then you would want your config to look like:

```
files: ["assets/application.css"]
```

(Not scss)

The same will be true for your javascripts. If you have trouble locating an asset, try outputing it to a page using the asset_path('name-of-asset') helper.

Comment: Do you mean like this `browser-sync start --proxy "myproject.dev" --files "["assets/application.css"]"`